# How can I declare a module (actually a Set.Make) in mli file?

Tags: ocaml

I have `airport.mli` and `airport.ml`.

---

In `airport.ml`, I have

```
module AirportSet = Set.Make(struct type t = airport let compare = compare end);;
```

This is no problem.

---

I then have a function

```
val get_all_airport : unit -> AirportSet.t;;
```

, which generates a `AirportSet`.

---

so in `airport.mli`, I need to show the `module AirportSet` so `AirportSet` is recognized.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
module AirportSet : (Set.S with type elt = airport)
```

(The parens are actually unnecessary, putting them there so that you know this is a signature expected, in the general case of the form `sig ... end`).

Answer (score 0):

The **elegant** solution is was gasche proposed; a more pragmatic/straight forward/naive solution is to simply use the ocaml-compiler `ocamlc` to infer (`-i`) the type of the module for you:

```
ocamlc -i airport.ml
```

which gives you a more verbose type like

```
AirportSet :
  sig
    type elt = airport
    type t
    val empty : t
    val is_empty : t -> bool
    val mem : elt -> t -> bool
...
    val split : elt -> t -> t * bool * t
end
```